# Advice on implementing a system to handle user's authentication expirations using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, session, authentication

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to handle user auhtentications expiring after 15 minutes of inactivity. I read the "[Ruby On Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-expiry)" that recommends, for safety reasons, to don't keep the authentication in the session because its values can be changed on the client side. So I decided to create a Model just to do that.

For the database I created a table that have these columns: "last_sign_in", "last_sign_out" and timestamps "created_at" and "updated_at". Each user have a dedicated row to store his/her authentication information.

My questions/doubts are:

1. Referring the performance of the system, is this approach still recommended when the database will contain a lot (thousands and thousands) of users? If no, what is the best approach to handle authentication expiration?
2. *In my case*, **how to implement** the code taking care of performance? That is, how to handle authentication expiration interacting as little as possible with the database and caching requests?
3. Adding the column "last_action" to the database table, in order to have the time information of the last action made by users, how much is advisable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**devise**](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem for authentication which have module named [**Rememberable**](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/rememberable.rb) that do cookies store and retrive for you.

> Rememberable manages generating and clearing token for remember the user
>   from a saved cookie. Rememberable also has utility methods for dealing
>   with serializing the user into the cookie and back from the cookie, trying
>   to lookup the record based on the saved information.
>   You probably wouldn't use rememberable methods directly, they are used
>   mostly internally for handling the remember token.

Comment: I am trying to implement code myself, not to use a gem... for that I would like to have some advice in order to solve some my doubt.